# my image is not displayed

Tags: android, image

I have a weird problem!
My application calls the phone's camera to take a picture.
The photo is taken and stored in the ad hoc directory successfully
However, when I open the photo is not displayed (black screen)
and when I send the photo by email I can open it in my pc.

Here is the code :

```
    String imageName = txtNomPhoto.getText().toString()+JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX;

    File dossier = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/DossierPhotos");

    if (!dossier.exists()){
        if (dossier.mkdir()){
        }
    }

    File mFichier = new File(dossier.getAbsolutePath(),imageName);

    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(mFichier);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_RESULT);
```

Thank you for your quick help.

Comment: did u added permition for reading exteranl strorage

Comment: pls explain properly..frm where r u trying to access the photo?..provide the code that u've used to access the photo..

Comment: I go mannually in "sdcard/DossierPhotos" to open and display my image taken by my application.